# Protobuf3: String validation with regex

Tags: regex, string, validation, protocol-buffers, protobuf-3

I have been using [Protobuf3](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3) to define a PB message:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package vioozer_protobuf;

message Update
{
  string sensor_id = 1;
  ...
}
```

In my system, sensors have a unique id format (a-la `SENSOR-1342r43`) that can easily be validated with a regex.

**Is there a way to add a regex validator to a protobuf field, so that only strings that adhere to the regex would be accepted into that field?**

Comment: Does this help: [go-proto-validators](https://github.com/mwitkow/go-proto-validators)?

Comment: Thanks! However, I'm looking for a solution within the language, not an external plugin.

Comment: I don't have a single clue then... But from my small experience, if someone created an external plugin, it's that it was missing from the language

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Protobuf does not support message validation out of the box, but it is possible to add it using plugin (that's the only way, however, it is not simple).

You can try to find existing plugin, or create your own (if there is no existing plugin for your language).

If you decide to write your own plugin, then first step is to define [a custom option](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#options) for fields:

```
package yourcompany;

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
    optional string validator = 51234;
}
```

This option allows you to specify regular expression for a concrete field. Then you apply your new custom option:

```
message Update {
    string sensor_id = 1 [(yourcompany.validator) = "SENSOR-???????"];
    // ...
}
```

Second, and more challenging step is to [write your own plugin](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/other) in order to add validation logic to generated code:

> Additionally, plugins are able to insert code into the files generated by other code generators. See the comments about "insertion points" in [plugin.proto](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.plugin.pb) for more on this. This could be used, for example, to write a plugin which generates RPC service code that is tailored for a particular RPC system. See the documentation for the generated code in each language to find out what insertion points they provide.

Your plugin must check value of your custom option and generate additional validation code for fields.

Comment: please check this project https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate

Comment: Nice, should try it out! 

P.S. It didn't exist at the moment I wrote my answer, but it was almost 3 years ago :)

Answer (score 9):

Please check this project protoc-gen-validate https://github.com/envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate

I wrote an example for Golang  here https://github.com/alexcpn/golang_grpc_test

With this you can give semantic validation as a annotation in proto and get it autogenerated as part of protobuff generation

```
message SearchRequest {
  string query = 1 [(validate.rules).string = {
                      pattern:   "([A-Za-z]+) ([A-Za-z]+)*$",
                      max_bytes: 50,
                   }];
  string email_id= 2 [(validate.rules).string.email = true];
  int32 page_number = 3;  // Which page number do we want?
  int32 result_per_page = 4;  // Number of results to return per page.
}
```

Server validation using generated stub

```
func (s *Server)Search(ctx context.Context, in *pb.SearchRequest) (*pb.SearchResponse, error){
    log.Printf("Received Emailid: %v", in.EmailId)
    log.Printf("Received Query: %v", in.Query)

    // Note this is the only place we use validate
    err := in.Validate()
    if err != nil {
        log.Warn("SearchRequest validation failed: %v", err)
```

Comment: thanks for the code it was helpful. But if I want to write custom validation in Go some thing like this  "string sensor_id = 1 [(yourcompany.validator) = "SENSOR-???????"];" how it can be achieved ?